# App Component is Getting Props Magically?

Tags: reactjs

I'm checking the code base of a functioning react web-app, and struggling to understand the following from the App.js file:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    let error = null
    if (this.props.error) {
      error = <ErrorMessage
        message={this.props.error.message}
        debug={this.props.error.debug} />
    }
    return (
      <Router>
        {this.props.isAuthenticated ?
        <div className="holder">
          <NavBar
            isAuthenticated={this.props.isAuthenticated}
...
```

Specifically, where does props (this.props.error and this.props.isAuthenticated) come from? Seems like it isn't defined anywhere. In Index.js, it renders the App component without passing in any props `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`.

Edit: at the bottom of App.js, it's exported with `export default withAuthProvider(App)`
and there's a file called AuthProvider.tsx which defines `error` and `isAuthenticated`.

Comment: It seems meaningless to me, where did you get this code from? Can you provide the source or more info

Comment: Props does not come magically, it must be passed in, if it's not passed in, it is undefined. This code may either call App with props elsewhere, or it would not be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `withAuthProvider` is a Higher-Order component. You can learn more about this pattern [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html). They're actually functions that take a React component as an argument (`App` in this case) and enhance it with props or logic. `withAuthProvider` wraps the `App` component and provides it the `error` and `isAuthenticated` props, while it could also implement some authentication logic for you.